# How to convert IBM Domino SSL keys (private key) to the OpenSSL format?

Tags: tls, webserver

I have a customer with an IBM Domino server. They offer a way to export SSL keys but in a weird proprietary format. Any idea on how to convert those to OpenSSL?

Basically I need to upload this key to an intermediate device that will do inspection and security. If I can bring it to OpenSSL, I'm golden.

Comment: How do you know its a proprietary format? There are several 'standard' file formats - perhaps you could provide a link to an exported (public or self-signed) certificate, then perhaps people would be able to see for themselves?

Comment: Better yet, a link to some documentation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the .kyr format, you can use a tool thats part of websphere called iKeyman (ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/lotus/tools/Domino/gsk5-ikeyman.zip).

A quick overview of what you need to do can be found here: http://labs.groupwave.be/index.php/2009/08/31/exporting-kyr-certificate-for-apache/

Comment: That seems to be the correct answer. I will see if it works. Thanks for your help!